# How to create responsive div widths without @media queries

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div elements nested in another:

```
<div id="master" style="width:100%">

<div id="child1">Content1</div>
<div id="child2">Content2</div>
<div id="child3">Content3</div>

</div>
```

Now `#master` is a responsive div, who's pixel width will vary with window size. I would like each child div to have `width:33.333%` providing that the content doesn't wrap. If the content does wrap, I would like the widths to be `100%`.

Note the content is variable, so I can't use traditional media queries. Can anyone think how I could start to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
try applying CSS to every div,

```
#master{
    width:100%;
    }
#child1, #child2, #child3{
    width:33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Along with this your requirement can be fulfilled using JavaScript, nothing just before `</body>` you need to include this javascript below:

```
var child1 = document.querySelector('#child1');
var child2 = document.querySelector('#child2');
var child3 = document.querySelector('#child3');

if((child1.offsetHeight < child1.scrollHeight) || (child1.offsetWidth < child1.scrollWidth)&&(child2.offsetHeight < child2.scrollHeight) || (child2.offsetWidth < child2.scrollWidth)&&(child3.offsetHeight < child3.scrollHeight) || (child3.offsetWidth < child3.scrollWidth)){
    // your element have overflow
    child1.style.width = "100%";
    child2.style.width = "100%";
    child3.style.width = "100%";
}
else{
    //your element don't have overflow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use This CSS

```
#master{
    width:100%;
}
#child1, #child2, #child3{
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

You can also use

```
    #child1, #child2, #child3{
   width:33.33%;
   float:left;
    }
```

Comment: That's not going to wrap to 100% though

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `min-width` property.

When the block will exceed its `min-width` then it will be dropped in to second line.

```
#child1, #child2, #child3{
    width:33%;
    min-width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can creative the responsive layout by using `flex` css attribute which is supportable for all latest browser.

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat;
}

#master {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#child1,#child2,#child3 {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: brown;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex: 1 1 160px;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="master">

<div id="child1">Content1</div>
<div id="child2">Content2</div>
<div id="child3">Content3</div>

</div>
```